# How to get default values on a form submitted via rest?

Tags: html, angularjs, web-services, rest

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked already. I have a form on a web page which is being submitted via a restful web service (it's actually using angular js). The question is how should I set default values on the form? (This is for creates as obviously on an edit I'll be getting values from the server anyway)

**An example**
Let's say we have a checkbox on the form to opt in/out of marketing emails.

```
I would like to receive marketing emails [x]
```

In this case the checkbox is defaulted to checked so they have to physically opt out. In the old world of generating html on the server I probably would have returned these defaults from the business layer and then generated the form html with the defaults set.

**Solution 1**
Set the default values in the client. As I'm using angular I could have a JS object that represents the default state of the form and use this to initialize the form on a create.

My problem with this approach is that it just feels a bit wrong to be putting business rules like this in the client.

**Solution 2**
Another option might be to hide fields that have default values and only let them be changed on an edit. This might be ok for some types of field but for our optin field they definitely need to review this. This could be done if the form initially displayed those fields without defaults, then when you click a button to continue the form is saved. The client could then do a get on the object just saved and display all fields with the now populated defaults.

I can't decide if I like this approach or not. It's more requests to the server so in that respect it's not very efficient. Depending on which fields have defaults it might look a bit odd suddenly being presented with some extra fields.

**Solution 3**
Finally we could create a rest web service to get the default state. I haven't seen any other examples of this so not sure of any conventions. Something like:

```
GET http://server/rest/myresource/default
```

Are there any conventions on this kind of thing? Something I've missed? Anyone done this themselves and found a way that works best?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about an editing form, you have some "defaults" (i.e. the already saved data) and the data that the user is inserting. So you basically get the data (via $http) and use it for extend the form fields (via `angular.extend`). Here is a fiddle which explains it better: http://jsfiddle.net/F9rD8/

Comment: Obviously on an edit you get the state from the server anyway. I should have made it clearer that this is on creates when we have a fresh form.

Comment: Just seen your angular.extend in the fiddle. That's basically my solution 1. It's still business rules in the presentation layer though? I was after more of a reasoning for going for one of these solutions rather than code.

Comment: It think this is the most angular-ish way of doing it; you can think of an "initialization" of the controller/form. Also, Angular can be seen as a business-presentation layer (it's basically a MVC).

Comment: The "angular way" always seems to be based on very simple web apps. If you work on an enterprise system you typically might have one vendor writing backend API's and another writing a web client interface. The backend system could have complicated business rules for determining default values. I wouldn't expect to duplicate these in the client where I may not even have all of the information present to decide. This is hypothetical but it's based on experience.

Comment: This is what I've ended up going with. angular.extend is useful. I'm not overly happy as I can see cases in future where this won't suffice but I'll have to cross that bridge when I come to it.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through your comments, I think the problem might be thinking of Angular framework as Presentation Layer. Yes - It is a client side framework, but when running on the client side, Angular provides the MVC Presentation Layer. The recommendation is to augment the  presentation layer with Angular "Services".

You might want to have an Angular Business "Service" that provides the defaults for the new form.

In the Angular world, your Layered architecture is essentially on the client side with Views and Controllers forming the presentation layer and both client side angular services and Server side APIs forming the business layer.

Angular services - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Hope that makes sense.